# Intent Service works but class it calls to do work stops when app is closed

Tags: android, android-notifications, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have an `IntentService` called `ReplyMessageIntentService`  in my app, and this service is responsible for receiving messages that comes from notification direct reply. The intent service does immediately calls a class `SaveMessage` that saves messages to a database. Other classes and activities in my app uses the `SaveMessage` class as well.

`ReplyMessageIntentService` and `SaveMessage` works well together. However, when the app is closed for a long period time, if I should reply to a notification, `ReplyMessageIntentService` is called as it should, works fine; `SaveMessage` is also called/initialized, but stops before even saving anything to the database. And the notification spinner in the notification tray continues to spin as the code stops before I can send feed back to cancel/update the notification.

I suspect I am using `IntentService` the wrong way, however, I do not want to write more code for saving data to the database inside the intent service as I already have code for that. If the previous statement is not the problem, I assume that `IntentService` has a certain duration of time that a task must be completed when app is closed for a period of time. Please let me know the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more good if you use workmanagar it will call alarm managar till API 14 and job scheduler after Api level 14 in background  also you can set different  constraint.

Comment: Yes, they want the job in the form of JobIntentService from what I am getting.

Comment: Generally speaking, using [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html) is even more better approach for background tasks, as it is more powerful and modern mechanism. If you have an extensive amount of background tasks then you should review the ability to use `WorkManager`. This [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/) can be very useful to choose appropriate solution.

Comment: This is correct. I am still using the `IntentService`, however I immediately direct it to the `Worker` class I have created so it will do work at the convenient time based on android resources. I am using `OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder` as I am only doing work on direct reply request, so no need for an alarm.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android 8.0 there are more strong restrictions for background services.To avoid them you should use [`JobIntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService) instead of `IntentService`. You can read more information about it [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).

Comment: This is good information, I am reading up on this now, I will update you on the outcome. This seems to be the correct answer using JobIntentService.